# Magento 1.9.2.0 Paypal Adaptive payment only vendor got payment , Owner not get commision

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I am facing issue Multi-vendor Store.

site using unirgy uMarketplace for multi vendor management.

Site is Using Paypal Adaptive payment.

When order placed Vendor get Payment in their paypal account but Owner does not get Commission Percentage of order.

in Exception log i got error 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Error: You do not have permission to execute this payment implicitly'

[image: Paypal App Screenshot]

Comment: you should contact uMarketplace extension provider for support

Comment: i think i am missing something in Paypal application

Comment: uMarketplace extension provider  support  is expire

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21520258/4349218

Comment: i have used chain payment ,  please see attached image in my question

Comment: any one have any idea about this issue? please help.